# can't call dismiss() on a custom AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I have created this custom `AlertDialog.Builder`

The problem is i want to dismiss it in the `onClick` of `mPositiveBTN`

`dismiss()` and `cancel()` are not defined ! How to do That?

this is it:

```
public class SendSmsDialog extends AlertDialog.Builder {

    private TextView mMessageTV;
    private Button mPositiveBTN;

    private EditText mobileNumberET;

    private Context mContext;

    public SendSmsDialog(@NonNull Context context, String title, String message) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((MainActivity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_sms_dialog, null);
        this.setView(dialoglayout);

        bindViews(dialoglayout);
        setListeners();


        this.setTitle(title);
        mMessageTV.setText(message);
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        mPositiveBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mobileNumberET.setEnabled(true);
                mobileNumberET.requestFocus();

                if (UtilitiesMethods.checkEnteredPhone(mobileNumberET.getText().toString())) {
                    ((MainActivity)mContext).doSendSMS(mobileNumberET.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    SendSmsDialog.this.dismiss(); //not defined
                    mobileNumberET.setError("Please enter a correct mobile number");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void bindViews(View dialoglayout) {
        mMessageTV = (TextView) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.msg_tv);
        mPositiveBTN = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.proceed_btn);
        mobileNumberET = (EditText) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.mobile_num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Always use of AlertDialog.Builder like this:

```
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private AlertDialog dialog;
.
.
.
.
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Add your account");
    builder.setView(rootView);
```

and for showing the dialog i use:

```
dialog = builder.show();
```

show method return a AlertDialog.so I can dismiss it by:

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

The builder itself is not a dialog, this means that you can't exactly call dismiss on the builder.

You should probably be extending the AlertDialog and not the AlertDialog.Builder.

Comment: I know that, but i still don't know how to terminate it!